# Convert timespan to datetime To add to a datetimepicker in C #

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datetimepicker

I want to display a time span data type in a datatimerpicker, I must first convert but I do not know how to do it

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan a = new TimeSpan(12, 00, 00);
    TimeSpan b = new TimeSpan(13, 00, 00);

    TimeSpan r = b - a;
    TimeSpan rr = new TimeSpan(r.Ticks / 2);

    MessageBox.Show("Test\n " + rr);   ///this is type TimeSpan 

    dateTimePicker.Value =Convert.ToDateTime(rr);   
    // error here
    // Additional Information: An object of type 'System.TimeSpan' 
    // can not be converted to type 'System.IConvertible'. "
}
```

Comment: Take a step back and tell us the business problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: TimeSpan is a period of time - not an actual Date/Time - you can add a TimeSpan to a specific DateTime but not convert directly to a DateTime.

Comment: How do you want to convert a TimeSpan to a DateTime? Do you want it to be as far in the future as the TimeSpan?

Comment: It looks like he wants to use a **Time**Span to represent a *time*.

Comment: Maybe you want something like this : http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radtimespanpicker/overview

Comment: Is this what you are after? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229631(v=vs.100).aspx  You have only defined "c#" as a tag.. What are you working with? (winforms/wpf/asp.net/asp.net mvc)

Comment: @mjwills My problem is that I have two different hours 12:00:00 and 13:00:00 I have to subtract 12:00:00 -13: 00 and then subtract, I would be 01:00:00 and that I have to divide by 2 It would be like this (01:00:00) / 2 = 00:30:00

Comment: @Michael Coxon Winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
TimeSpan a = new TimeSpan(12, 00, 00);
TimeSpan b = new TimeSpan(13, 00, 00);

TimeSpan r = b - a;
TimeSpan rr = new TimeSpan(r.Ticks / 2);

MessageBox.Show("Test\n " + rr);   ///this is type TimeSpan 

dateTimePicker.Value =  DateTime.Now.Date.AddMilliseconds(rr.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> This may in no way be an answer to your question - take it as just an insight into what you are trying to ask and then we can maybe create a real question/answer for it.

Date/Time pickers must have a date component. However, we can 'ignore' the date part..

I can only speculate due to the vagueness of the question... but here goes.. my *"could be's"* are how it will be expressed in the end...

```
TimeSpan a = new TimeSpan(12, 00, 00);       // 12 hours (could be midday)
TimeSpan b = new TimeSpan(13, 00, 00);       // 13 hours (could be 1 pm)

TimeSpan r = b - a;                          // 1 hour (could be 1 am)

TimeSpan rr = new TimeSpan(r.Ticks / 2);     // 30 minutes (could be 12:30 am)

dateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now.Add(rr); // current date time plus 30 minutes

// -- OR --

dateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now.Date.Add(rr); // current date plus 30 minutes
                                                  // eg: 2017-08-29 00:30:00
```

I think it is the last one you are looking for but with this added to the mix...

```
dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
```

---

See this for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229631(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display only time in `DateTimePicker` control just change the `Format` property value to `Time`, however, if you are looking for control to use it as counter, I suggest you use `TextBox` or `Label` or something else :)

Comment: I already did this process, but it does not work, I need a simple example, I work with windosForm

Comment: What do you mean by "I already did this process"? You used textbox as a counter and it doesn't work? First of all, tell us please :) what exactly are you trying to achieve?